# NaiveBayes.active_trail_nodes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'variables'

Tags: python, naivebayes, pgmpy

I run this code and get this error

```
def predict(data, inf, target_variable):
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for _, data_point in data.iterrows():
        if 'index' in data_point:
            del data_point['index']
        result = inf.query(
            variables=[target_variable],
            evidence=data_point.to_dict(),
            show_progress=False,
        )
        values = result.state_names[target_variable]
        for i, val in enumerate(values):
            results[val].append(result.values[i])
    return results
from pgmpy.inference import VariableElimination
nb_inference = VariableElimination(nb_model)
nb_results = predict(test_no_target,nb_inference,target_variable)
nb_mean_results = {}
for k, v in nb_results.items():
nb_mean_results[k] = np.nanmean(v)
```

TypeError: NaiveBayes.active_trail_nodes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'variables'
I run this with pgmpy version 0.1.24

Comment: This code does not have a call to `active_trail_nodes()`, therefore the error must be happening in some other code that you have not shown.  Please show the full error traceback message.